# SqlAlchemy join limiting dataset

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This search returns ~2,000 people. I want to find everyone that doesn't have an attached resume

```
candidates = db_session.query(Jobs).\
filter(and_(
    Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE',
    Jobs.interview_result == 'INCLINED',
    or_(Jobs.level == '5', Jobs.level =='6'),
    Jobs.family_id == 'SDE',
)).all()
```

So I tried to do a join.

This search only returns ~70 results. Presumably everyone that has an attached resume.

```
candidates = db_session.query(Jobs).\
join(Resumes, Resumes.candidate_id == Jobs.candidate_id).\
filter(and_(
    Jobs.interview_type == 'IN_HOUSE',
    Jobs.interview_result == 'INCLINED',
    or_(Jobs.level == '5', Jobs.level =='6'),
    Jobs.family_id == 'SDE',
)).all()
```

It seems like its reducing the results to everyone that has a resume versus returning `None` in the column where the resume doesn't exist.

How do I write this so I can find everyone, regardless of whether they have an attached resume or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `.outerjoin` (instead of `.join`) 
considering `Jobs` table (perceived as "people") as "**left**" table and `Resumes` - as "**right**" table.

Comment: I just found something similar! Thank you.